# Parse JS expression from a string

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

Given a string such as (which is a javascript source file):

```
"...attr1: i, TARGET: <JS_EXPRESSION>, attr3: {..."
```

How can I parse out the Javascript expression, using the known `TARGET` key?

The JS expression can be arbitrarily complicated and contain commas, so it looks like regex won't do apart from finding the initial target key, `TARGET`. The surrounding code can also contain any arbitrary JS code.

Here is what I tried to prove that this wasn't a homework assignment:

```
return source.replace(/TARGET: ([^,]*),/g, function(a, b){
  return operationOnExpression(b);
});
```

But this fails in more complex cases of `<E>`, e.g. `console.log('hi', 'there');`

Comment: And? Have you tried solving the problem on your own? Could you add a [mcve] to your Question, that highlights what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: What does a full string look like? Is it perhaps JSON?

Comment: If arbitrary code can come before and after `TARGET` there is no way to parse it

Comment: @Luca I can't provide a minimal example because I am building a webpack loader. This is the simplest I could make my question. I need a way to parse out this value

Comment: Yes, you should show us what you tried to get that value. It doesn't matter what you need this for, just show us, that you put some effort into solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @luca Ok, I will update my question with my wrong solution.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 2):

you can extract the expression using a couple of splits and create a script tag containing that expression and append it to the `head`

```js
const str = "...attr1: i, TARGET: console.log('here', 1), attr3: {..."

const exp = str.split('TARGET')[1].split(',').slice(0, -1).join().slice(1)

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = exp;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This fails, when `TARGET` is `console.log('here', 'there')`, thus it doesn't fit the requirements

Comment: @Taki, thank you for your answer, but if you pass something like `console.log('here', 1)`, then this breaks which is my problem exactly!

Comment: @Luca it's not perfect and this is just an example but the goal is to give him an idea about what to do and he can arrange the way he gets the expression.

Comment: Nice, that seems to have done it. At least for this String. As I wrote in my comment, if arbitrary code can come before and after the `TARGET`, you can't parse it

Comment: @Taki You are so smart :)

Comment: @Luca yes, you're right, but since I know what TARGET is, I can grep for that and lazily evaluate to get a string similar to the example that I posted in my question

Comment: @Taki Maybe I got ahead of myself :) `... { TARGET: 'timer', onClick: props.loseRound, etc etc` now breaks it because of the last comma. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: the question was about how to parse `js` from a `string` ,my snippet answers that , to get the expression in the string is up to you since you posted `JS_EXPRESSION` instead of the real one, this will work with : `...attr1: i, TARGET: console.log('here', 1); console.log(2), attr3: {...` , i don't see a reason for unnaccepting but you can use dev tools and see what's the content of `script` tag in the `head` and adjust the `split` and the `slice` values to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the values to the left of the TARGET column can't contain commas, you could consume them, searching ahead to the next comma until you've seen the right number of "columns" or you see "TARGET" as the start of the next column. Same for columns to the right. In Javascript, you could use `substr` and `indexOf` repeatedly to do that.

If that's no good, more information, like what language you're using, things you've already tried, whether the JS expression is surrounded by quote marks, would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect. The string is an entire, valid JS file. I am using JS to parse.

Comment: A webpack loader? Neat. I don't see any way to parse arbitrary JS reliably in one "column" in the middle of other data without basically parsing everything else then parsing what's left as target. Don't suppose you can link to any docs that describe the format you're dealing with? Is it a standard webpack thing?